# Google found AdMob SDK in my App even though I'm not using it

Tags: android, sdk, dependencies, google-play, admob

I know that this question already has been posted, but the solutions couldn't help me.
I have an android app that is using two play services dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
```

Google says they detected two Ad SDKs in the app, Version: 14, SDK: AdMob. I checked all dependencies and couldn't find any Ad SDK. Therefore I am a little lost where look for the Ad SDKs and how to get rid of them. For now the app is still available in the play store even though I read that google would delete apps which claim to have no ads but using Ad SDKs.

Comment: Try to use Android Studio tools in "Build - Analyze APK" and check for AdMob package name if it's present.

Comment: I checked but there's nothing obvious to find. 

ArchivePathEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/play-services-places-placereport.properties"
ArchivePathEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/play-services-location.properties"
ArchivePathEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/play-services-basement.properties"
ArchivePathEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/play-services-tasks.properties"
ArchivePathEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/play-services-maps.properties"
ArchivePathEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/play-services-base.properties"

Comment: You have to check inside the final APK if the packagename starting with "com.google.android.gms.ads" is present. I suppose yes, because Google can warn you about AdMob only in this way: by checking APK's package names.

Comment: Sorry if I have to ask stupid questions but I should analyze the APK (Build -> Analyze APK) and there look for "com.google.android.gms.ads" or something like that? Because I did that and found nothing. Could it be possible that this warning (that I use Ad SDK) is inherited from an earlier version of the app?

Comment: Maybe you have to learna HOW analyze APKs first: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer You need to find DEX files and open them from Android Studio, then navigate through "folders" like "com" -> "google" --> "android" --> "gms" ... and check if there is an "ads" subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

If your app or one of the libraries in your app are using Identifier for Advertisers (IDFA), Google Play will tell you **We found ad SDKs in your app**

[image: Google Play Console screenshot of ads]

If your app is not using ads do not worry too much about it, in this case it is a false positive and Google know that and tell you to leave it as is (**see the image above**)

I found out that most of analytics SDKs are using (IDFA) to recognize unique users efficiently.

for example [OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-collected-by-the-onesignal-sdk) SDK uses this.

> The Google Ad Id and Apple IFV are used for device matching. See OneSignal Player ID for more details.